# Balanced partition

Tags: algorithm

I know this was talked over a lot here, but I am struggling with this problem.

We have a set of numbers, e.g [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1], and we need to break it into two subsets, so the each sum is equal or difference is minimal.

I've seen [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), this [page](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/) (problem 7) and a [blog entry](http://ronzii.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/balanced-partition-problem/).

But every algorithm listed is giving only YES/NO result and I really don't understand how to use them to print out two subsets (e.g S1 = {5, 4} and S2 = {5, 3, 3}). What am I missing here?

Comment: You can probably get the subsets by traversing the computed table backwards. This is a standard strategy in dynamic programming problems.

Comment: well, could you please elaborate on this a little bit more?

Comment: Is there a maximum amount of numbers that can be in your list, if so what is it?  If the solution the algorithm produced was very close to optimal but not necessarily optimal, would that be good enough?

Comment: no maximum amount and I really need the best solution possible :-)

Answer (score 4):

The pseudo-polynomial algorithm is designed to provide an answer to the *decision problem*, not the *optimization problem*. However, note that the last row in the table of booleans in [the example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Example) indicates that the current set is capable of summing up to N/2.

In the last row, take the first column where the boolean value is `true`. You can then check what the actual value of the set in the given column is. If the sets summed value is N/2 you have found the first set of the partition. Otherwise you have to check which set is capable of being the difference to N/2. You can use the same approach as above, this time for the difference *d*.

Answer (score 1):

This will be **O(2^N)**. No Dynamic Programming used here. You can print result1, result2 and difference after execution of the function. I hope this helps.

```
vector<int> p1,p2;
vector<int> result1,result2;
vector<int> array={12,323,432,4,55,223,45,67,332,78,334,23,5,98,34,67,4,3,86,99,78,1};

void partition(unsigned int i,long &diffsofar, long sum1,long sum2)
{
    if(i==array.size())
    {
        long diff= abs(sum1 - sum2);
        if(diffsofar > diff)
        {
            result1 =  p1;
            result2 = p2;
            diffsofar = diff;
        }
        return;
    }

    p1.push_back(array[i]);
    partition(i+1,diffsofar,sum1+array[i],sum2);
    p1.pop_back();

    p2.push_back(array[i]);
    partition(i+1,diffsofar,sum1,sum2+array[i]);
    p2.pop_back();

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem recently, and I posted a question about it (here: [Variant of Knapsack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088778/variant-of-knapsack/)). The difference in my case is that the resulting subsets must be the same size (if the original set has an even number of elements). In order to assure that, I added a few lines to @Sandesh Kobal answer;

```
void partition(unsigned int i,long &diffsofar, long sum1,long sum2)
{
    int maxsize = (array.size()+1)/2;

    if(p1.size()>maxsize)
        return;

    if(p2.size()>maxsize)
        return;

    if(i==array.size())
    {
        ...
```

Also, after both calls to `partition`, I added `if(diffsofar==0) return;`. If we already found an optimal solution, it makes no sense to keep searching...

Answer (score 0):

All the articles I've seen take a dynamic programming approach. Do we really need one?

Suppose the array given is `arr`

Use the following algorithm :

1. Sort the array in descending order
2. Create two empty arrays, `a = []` and `b = []`
3. `sum_a = sum_b = 0`

```
for x in arr:
    if sum_a > sum_b:
        b.append(x)
        sum_b += x
    else:
        a.append(x)
        sum_a += x
```

The absolute difference between `sum_a` and `sum_b` would be the minimum possible difference between the two subsets.

Consider `arr = [3,1,1,2,2,1]`

Sorting the array : `arr = [3,2,2,1,1,1]`

```
a = [], b = []
a = [3], b = []
a = [3], b = [2]
a = [3], b = [2,2]
a = [3,1], b = [2,2]
a = [3,1,1], b = [2,2]
a = [3,1,1], b = [2,2,1]
```

`sa = 5, sb = 5`

Minimum difference : `5 - 5 = 0`