# Performance of coin splitting algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, performance, recursion, split

My question is about a CodeFu practice problem (2012 round 2 problem 3). It basically comes down to splitting an array of integers in two (almost) equal halves and returning the smallest possible difference between the two. I have included the problem description below. As noted in the comments this can be described as a [balanced partition problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781159/balanced-partition), which is a problem in the realm of [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Now similar problems have been discussed a lot, but I was unable find an efficient solution for this particular one. The problem is of course that the number of possible combinations to traverse soon grows too large for a brute force search (at least when using recursion). I have a recursive solution that works fine for all but the largest problem sets. I tried to add some optimizations that stop the recursion early, but the performance is still too slow to solve some arrays of the maximum length (30) within the 5 second maximum allowed by CodeFu. Any suggestions for how to improve or rewrite the code would be very welcome. I would also love to know if it might help to make the iterative version.

**Update:** on [this fine site](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/) there is a theoretical discussion of the balanced partition problem, which gives a good idea of how to go about and solve this in a dynamic way. That is really what I am after, but I do not know how to put the theory into practice exactly. The movie mentions that the elements in the two subcollections can be found "using the old trick of back pointers", but I don't see how.

### Problem

> You and your friend have a number of coins with various amounts. You
>   need to split the coins in two groups so that the difference between
>   those groups in minimal.
>
> E.g.   Coins of sizes 1,1,1,3,5,10,18 can be split as:  1,1,1,3,5 and
>   10,18  1,1,1,3,5,10 and 18  or  1,1,3,5,10 and 1,18 The third
>   combination is favorable as in that case the difference between the
>   groups is only 1.    Constraints:   coins will have between 2 and 30
>   elements inclusive   each element of coins will be between 1 and
>   100000 inclusive
>
> Return value:   Minimal difference possible when coins are split into
>   two groups

NOTE: the CodeFu rules state that the execution time on CodeFu's server may be no more than 5 seconds.

### Main Code

```
Arrays.sort(coins);

lower = Arrays.copyOfRange(coins, 0,coins.length-1);
//(after sorting) put the largest element in upper
upper = Arrays.copyOfRange(coins, coins.length-1,coins.length);            

smallestDifference = Math.abs(arraySum(upper) - arraySum(lower));
return findSmallestDifference(lower, upper, arraySum(lower), arraySum(upper), smallestDifference);
```

### Recursion Code

```
private int findSmallestDifference (int[] lower, int[] upper, int lowerSum, int upperSum, int smallestDifference) {
    int[] newUpper = null, newLower = null;
    int currentDifference = Math.abs(upperSum-lowerSum);
    if (currentDifference < smallestDifference) {
        smallestDifference = currentDifference;
    } 
    if (lowerSum < upperSum || lower.length < upper.length || lower[0] > currentDifference 
            || lower[lower.length-1] > currentDifference 
            || lower[lower.length-1] < upper[0]/lower.length) {
        return smallestDifference;
    }
    for (int i = lower.length-1; i >= 0 && smallestDifference > 0; i--) {           
       newUpper = addElement(upper, lower[i]);
       newLower = removeElementAt(lower, i);
       smallestDifference = findSmallestDifference(newLower, newUpper, 
               lowerSum - lower[i], upperSum + lower [i], smallestDifference);
    }
    return smallestDifference;
}
```

### Data Set

Here is an example of a set that takes too long to solve.

> {100000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,
>               60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,
>               60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,60000,
>               60000,60000,60000}

If you would like the entire source code, I have put it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/weHDoP).

Comment: Matthias: thanks for the edit (adding titles). This being my first question I hadn't thought to do it like that.

Comment: I have a suggestion, though not a solution.  Sort the coins in descending order.  Make an array of totals of 'remaining coins' from that array, i.e. first element has total of all coins, second of all but the first, etc.  Go through the first array and use the second to decide which pile to put each coin in.  I suppose recursion might prove useful if you make a tree structure and decide by letting the algorithm chase down the entire tree to a conclusion before ending.  Use half of the total of all coins as a target.

Comment: if you are looking for performance/optimization issue you should give comparable results and define your goals.

Comment: That sounds a lot like a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) task...

Comment: Roman C: thank you for the suggestion, but my question is really not about comparing milliseconds but about improvements to get to a different order of computation. The goal is to have the algorithm run efficiently for all possible arrays of length 30.

Comment: brimborium: thanks for another great edit (putting source code on Ideone) didn't know that either ;-)

Comment: "similar problems have been discussed a lot, but I still can't find an efficient solution for this particular one." Actuall this precise problem (not just 'similar') is well know problem (Balanced partition), there are not efficient solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781159/balanced-partition http://wp.me/p1i4zv-4i

Comment: @titusn We are not notified if you refer to us just by name. Add a `@` before the name (like I did with your name on this comment, although I didn't need to because as OP, you get a notification anyway). Then we get a notifitcation. ;)

Comment: @leonbloy thank you for the reference! I was looking for a decent name for the problem all over. I knew this had to be a standard problem, but I was unable to locate it.

Comment: @titusn Even before the edits were made, your question was structured very good! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `N` is the sum of all coins. We need to find a subset of coins, where the sum of its coins is closest to `N/2`. Let's calculate all possible sums and choose the best one. In worst case we may expect 2^30 possible sums, but this may not happen, because the largest possible sum is 100K*30, that is 3M - much less than 2^30 which would be about 1G. So an array of 3M ints or 3M bits should be sufficient to hold all possible sums.

So we have array `a` and `a[m] == 1` if and only if `m` is a possible sum.

We start from zeroed array and have `a[0]=1`, because the sum `0` is possible (one has no coins).

```
for (every coin)
  for (int j=0; j<=3000000; j++)
    if (a[j] != 0)
      // j is a possible sum so far
      new_possible_sum = j + this_coin
      a[new_possible_sum] = 1
```

When you finish in 30 * 3M steps you will know all possible sums. Find the number `m` that is closest to `N/2`. Your result is `abs(N-m - m)`. I hope I fit in time and memory bounds.

**Edit**: A correction is needed and 2 optimizations:

1. Walk the array in descending order. Otherwise a dollar coin would overwrite the whole array in one go.
2. Limit the size of the array to `N+1` (including 0), to solve smaller coin sets faster.
3. Since we almost always get 2 identical results: `m` and `N-m`, reduce the array size to `N/2`. Add bound check for `new_possible_sum`. Throw away greater possible sums.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken 3 million bits is not sufficient because OP doesn't merely want to find the difference between the two sets: he also wants the exact coins in each set.  But I agree that a dynamic programming solution here is the way to go.

Comment: @TacticalCoder: In fact I do not need the exact coins in each set, since the original requirements state that only the difference between the sets has to be returned. So this solution seems the best possible iterative approach. It would of course be very nice to have the exact coins too.

Comment: I will test this approach tomorrow, looks very promising again. I will at least give you both a +1 for effort as soon as I can actually vote again (I used them for today).

Comment: I don't know if it is the case in this problem, but when they require only the number, it means that only this is possible for given time and memory limits. So I don't aim for computing more. I only try to do what is requested in the description.

Comment: @Jarekczek spoken like a truly wise man! A programmer should never deliver more or less than neccessary.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that this solution is working (with the edits) and indeed is very fast. I did not try the last optimization, because it was not necessary in this case. Thanks a lot for the interesting discussion! Here's the [final code](http://ideone.com/O2HQnO).

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy to know this works without having to code it myself :) I used to take part in such competitions, but finally I found them too exhausting and quit for good.

Comment: @titusn Sometimes it makes sence to deliver more if you assume that that requirement will come soon. Then you can just say "oh, that's already in my code." and you'll be the hero. ;)

Comment: @brimborium Yes, I see your point. Although the 'real' engineer (Scotty) would always hold back a bonus like that, come up with a large estimate and only when pressed say: "Ok, I can do it in a few hours".

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** *just to be clear: I've written this answer before the additional limitation of running in under five seconds was specified in the question. I've also written it just to show that sometimes brute force is possible even when it seems that it's not.  So this answer is not meant to be the "best" answer to this problem: it's precisely meant to be a brute force solution.  As a side benefit this little solution may help someone writing another solution to verify in an acceptable time that their answer for "large" arrays are correct.*

> The problem is of course that the number of possible combinations to
>   traverse soon grows too large for a brute force search.

Given the problem as initially stated (before the max running time of 5 seconds was specified), I totally dispute that statement ;)

You specifically wrote that the maximum length was 30.

Note that I'm not talking about other solutions (like, say, a dynamic programming solution that may or may not work given your constraints).

What I'm saying is that *2<sup>30</sup>* is not big.It's a bit more than one billion and that's it.

A modern CPU can execute, on one core, billions of cycles per second.

You don't need to recurse to solve this: recursing shall blow your stack. There's an easy way to determine all the possible left / right combination: simply count from 0 to 2 exp 30 - 1 and check every bit (decide that, say, a bit on means you put the value to the left and off means you put the value to the right).

So given the problem statement if I'm not mistaken the following approach, without any optimization, should work:

```
  public static void bruteForce( final int[] vals) {
    final int n = vals.length;
    final int pow = (int) Math.pow(2, n);
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = pow -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int diff = 0;
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
            diff += (i & (1<<j)) == 0 ? vals[j] : -vals[j];

        }
        if ( Math.abs(diff) < min ) {
            min = Math.abs(diff);
            val = i;
        }
    }

    // Some eye-candy now...
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++ ) {
        System.out.print( i == 0 ? "Left:" : "Right:");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(((val & (1 << j)) == (i == 0 ? 0 : (1<<j)) ? " " + vals[j] : ""));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

For example:

```
bruteForce( new int[] {2,14,19,25,79,86,88,100});
Left: 2 14 25 79 86
Right: 19 88 100


bruteForce( new int[] {20,19,10,9,8,5,4,3});
Left: 20 19
Right: 10 9 8 5 4 3
```

On an array of 30 elements, on my cheap CPU it runs in 125 s.  That's for a "first draft", totally unoptimized solution running on a single core (the problem as stated is trivial to parallelize).

You can of course get fancier and reuse lots and lots and lots of intermediate results, hence solving an array of 30 elements in less than 125 s.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this really elegant and smart solution. It looks very good indeed and I will check it out, but it will very probably work just as expected.

Comment: I just tested it and the computation for the large example set I included still takes quite some time (about two minutes on a very fast system). I will adjusted the post to specify more clearly the performance requirements and what I found so far.

Comment: that is strange though, that you would get such a different result. I really just copy-pasted your code and left out the screen part. How can the performance differ so much between our systems? Anyway, the real benchmark here is the performance on the CodeFu site. You can check it yourself, the solution is much too slow for them. I still love the elegance of your approach though.

Comment: @titusn I think, TacticalCoder means 125 **s** and not 125 ms, because that's what I get for your size-30 test set. And brute force is surely not optimal at all. His approach is *O(n*2^n)*.

Comment: And no, I don't have anything against hairdresser, they are wonderful people and it's a cool and creative job. ;)

Comment: @brimborium: Ah yes, that would explain it. I know that it's not that efficient, but I still love anything that involves bit shifting. Can't help it ;-)

Comment: @brimborium: +1... Yup I meant 125 seconds of course, not 125 ms ; )

Comment: I wouldnt be so quick to dismiss this solution as useless. Its an excellent example of the old maxim: 'First make it work, then make it work fast' You can add in all sorts of unit tests, with confidence that your underlying algorithm is sound, and then refactor mercilessly (or even rewrite) to get performance.

Comment: @Visage I didn't downvote it. The problem here is the following: While you **can** get performance by some optimizations, you will always be stuck with exponential runtime while I think you can apply some sort of dynamic programming approach and reach polynomial runtime. And as that approach is **very** different, you can not reach it by adding optimizations to the brute force approach. You simply have to recode the whole thing.

Comment: So +1 for the *first make it work, then make it work fast* approach, but it has it's limits... Always keep that in mind.

Comment: @titusn: glad you like it ; )   The "trick" regarding bit shifting is to use each bit to represent a choice (on or off) or, in this case, either "left" or "right".  It has the added benefit (in addition of being quite fast and non-recursive) of working as a simple *for* loop: the integer in your loop becomes your combination of left/right values.  But it's not an unknown technique or anything: it's a very common way to quickly generate all the possible combinations, I simply did apply it to the problem at hand.