# Partitioning floating-point array

Tags: algorithm

While writing code, i found the following problem, to state it in a simple way:

> Partition an array of floats *X* in array *A* and *B* such that the difference between the sum of the values in *A* and the sum of values of *B* is minimized

This was part of an investigation I was doing, but I can't find a way to efficiently perform this operation.

**Edit:**

To answer to those who believe this is from a math contest like PE, SPOJ or homework, it is not. I just had curiosity about this when i was trying to partition an already factorized number *p*  in the set of factors *a* and *b* such that b=a+1. If we take logs from both sides, we can show this problem is equivalent to minimize a diference of sums, but that is where i have got stuck.

Comment: An investigation into what? This week's homework?

Comment: Looks like variant of subset sum problem.

Comment: No, not really. I was trying to partition a number in its prime factors and then reorder them so that i find two consecutives numbers a and b. It has nothing to do with homework, just curiosity.

Comment: Also, it is not from a math-programming contest like PE, SPOJ, or any other.

Comment: This is just Partition Problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) re-stated as an optimization problem.

Comment: As multiplying is way too expensive in large calculations I think that a summing their (precalculated) logarithms would be way easier. The problem I face with the computing partition problem is that it is related to integers, and it is natural for logarithms to be irrational in my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Balanced partition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781159/balanced-partition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a first simple idea. Use dynamic programming methods.
I assume that this problem can be transformed to knapsack problem. You need to pick items from `X` (there'll be array `A`) to maximize sum but don't exceed `(sumX - sumA)` value (there'll be sum of items from array `B`). For algorithm to solve knapsack problem by dynamic programming approach look at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) e.g.
This solution can be wrong, btw... but even if it'll work I'm more than sure that more efficient, elegant and short solutions exist.

Comment: I will give a try to those algorithms, and see how it develops. Thanks.

Comment: My last question: If i search incrementally, each time adding one factor of p (in this case, adding one element to the array), is there an optimized knapsack algorithm for this?

Comment: @chubakueno I honestly exactly don't know and if I understand you right there's no optimal incremental [by factors] strategy, imo. I think the best way to use smth like "Meet-in-the-middle" method from "Knapsack problem" wiki page. And don't expect optimal algorithms for NP-complete problem :) And keep in mind there're good approximate algorithms - maybe you don't need precise answer and "good in average" will be enough?